# jQuery Slider Behaving oddly when moving .addClass to an unselected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've successfully made a jQuery slider, with click events on .arrow-next1 and .arrow-prev1. All of my elements are visible in HTML and I'm using CSS to only show the .active-skill1 and .active-title1 classes.

Everything works properly except for the code relating to .arrow-prev1 in conjunction with my .active-title1 class.

Here's how the HTML is setup:

```
<h3>
    <i class="icon icon-header ion-code-working"></i> Programming
    <span class="title1 active-title1"> [example1]</span>
    <span class="title1"> [example2]</span>
    <span class="title1"> [example3]</span>
</h3>
```

What seems to happen is my .active-title1 jumps up to the icon before jumping back to the example3 span.

Here's my JS (I put *'s on the relevent lines affecting the titles for the previous arrow)

```
var main = function() {

$('.arrow-next1').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-skill1');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot1');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    var currentTitle = $('.active-title1');
    var nextTitle = currentTitle.next();    

    if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
        nextSlide = $('.skill1').first();    
    }

    if(nextDot.length == 0) {
       nextDot = $('.dot1').first();    
    }

    if(nextTitle.length == 0) {
       nextTitle = $('.title1').first();  
    }

    currentTitle.removeClass('active-title1');
    nextTitle.addClass('active-title1');

    currentSlide.fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-skill1');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(900).addClass('active-skill1');
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot1');
    nextDot.fadeIn(900).addClass('active-dot1');
});

$('.arrow-prev1').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-skill1');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
    var currentDot = $('.active-dot1');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();


*    var currentTitle = $('.active-title1');
*    var prevTitle = currentTitle.prev();

*    if(prevTitle.length == 0) {
*        prevTitle = $('.title1').last();
*    }

    if(prevSlide.length == 0) {
        prevSlide = $('.skill1').last();
    }

    if(prevDot.length == 0) {
        prevDot = $('.dot1').last();    
    }

*   currentTitle.removeClass('active-title1');
*   prevTitle.addClass('active-title1');

    currentSlide.fadeOut(0).removeClass('active-skill1');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(900).addClass('active-skill1');
    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot1');
    prevDot.fadeIn(900).addClass('active-dot1');
});
```

Note: I can get it to work as intended if I put the Span's in a div like this:

```
    <h3><i class="icon icon-header ion-code-working"></i> Programming
        <div class=title">
            <span class="title1 active-title1"> [example1]</span>
            <span class="title1"> [example2]</span>
            <span class="title1"> [example3]</span>
        </div>
    </h3>
```

Except the [Skill1], [Skill2] & [Skill3] end up on a different line below the Programming Header 3. I want it to look like this on 1 line: **(icon)Programming [Example1]**

Does anyone know why my code isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Because span's are default to display:inline but divs are display:block. Try to change your .title1 css class to display:block or display:inline-block. That should solve the jumping problem.

Comment: Ya, I got what you meant, if I apply the "display: inline;" to the ".title" div from my last code section it works like you said.

I'm really curious why my javascript doesn't work for previous arrows but does for next, I have to assume that there's a bug in that code that I don't see, but I appreciate your workaround!

Comment: Can you put that plugin in a fiddle, let's take a look. I am pretty sure there is a small glitch in css definitions that is causing it.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wx1p2mxy/
I couldn't figure out how to get the icons for the arrows to show up in the fiddle though...